# obtener datos custom-select con handelbars y js

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Buen día compañeros del foro, estoy trabajando en un proyecto mysql, con Handlebars, node, y javascript. Mi duda es la siguiente tengo este fragmento y ya muestra la lista. Pero al recibir parametros por js no me funciona.

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <label class="input-group-text" for="FULLNAME">Nombre Completo</label>
                                </div>                                                         
                                <select class="custom-select" id="FULLNAME">                                     
                                <option disabled selected>Nombre Completo</option>
                                 {{#each namec}}
                               <option value={{NOMBRE}}>{{NOMBRE}}</option> 
                               {{/each}}                                                           
                                </select>                                                 
                            </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para recibir parametros:

```html
router.post('/add', async (req,res) =>{  
    const{USERNAME,PASSWORD,FULLNAME,ID_EMPLEADO} =req.body;
    const users = {
        USERNAME,
        PASSWORD,                
        FULLNAME,
        ID_EMPLEADO

    }        
    await pool.query('INSERT INTO users set ?',[users]);
    req.flash('success', 'Registro guardado correctamente');    
    res.redirect('/users');    
});
```

Estoy recibiendo parametros null en del custom-select
[image: Estoy recibiendo parametros null en del custom-select]

Comment: el label de fullname no tiene un name como tal....  `name="FULLNAME"`

Comment: Al `select` es al que le falta el `name`. Y no menos importante, deberías validar que datos recibe el BE para evitar que se "rompa"

Comment: Gracias parece que ya me habia bloqueado y no entendia el porque, pense que el id y name de alguna manera podian ser lo mismo pero ahora entiendo que ya no.
Buena respuesta a ambos.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que en esta línea tienes el problema:

```
<select class="custom-select" id="FULLNAME">
```

Deberías reemplazarla por algo así:

```
<select class="custom-select" name="FULLNAME" id="FULLNAME">
```

Los formularios utilizan el valor del atributo name para identificar el elemento a enviar, si solo pones el id sin name no se enviará el dato.

Espero te sirva.